# How can I call a function from another screen in "react-navite"?

Tags: javascript, react-native

The mobile app has two screens (screen_1 and screen_2). There is data that is stored in screen_1 (in AsyncStorage). To update this data, I need to call the function that is located in screen_1. Please tell me if I can call a function from screen_2 that is located in screen_1, and if so, how?

Comment: It is better to see a code example, that specifies the question and related issue

Answer (score 0):

you didin't seem to provide where the screens are located in file structure but I am going to explain the export/import process to you and then you can add your file names in the specified areas. You should write

```js
export {FUNCTION NAME};
```

in the document where the function is placed (screen 1)

then to access this export, you should add:

```js
import {FUNCTION NAME} from '.path/to/file';
```

As I have noted I don't know where your screen1 is placed. if it is nested in another file then you should do '../path/to/file'

If it is in the same data structure (which I assumed in my code) then this should work fine and know you can access your function